# Is there is any result claiming that there cannot be any other twin Mersenne primes?

Tags: prime-numbers, twin-primes

There are 3 known **Twin Mersenne Primes**: $M3$ and $M5$, $M5$ and $M7$, $M17$ and $M19$. More precisely, if both $M(p)$ and $M(p+2)$ are both prime, then they are called Twin Mersenne Primes.

My question is: Is there is any result claiming that there cannot be any other twin Mersenne primes

Comment: There is no result on whether or not there are infinitely many Mersenne primes, so I would doubt that there is any result on whether or not there are infinitely many **twin** Mersenne primes. To make this case stronger, there is no result even on whether or not there are infinitely many twin primes.

Comment: @barak, OP is not asking whether there are infinitely many, but whether there are *any* (beyond M19).

Comment: @GerryMyerson: True. If there was a large amount of known Mersenne primes (even without a formal proof for an infinite amount of them), then my case would be very weak indeed. But since there are only some $40$ known Mersenne primes, asking whether or not there are any Mersenne twin primes beyond the $7$th Mersenne prime is "rather equivalent" to asking whether or not there is a finite amount of Mersenne twin primes out of the (yet unproven) infinite amount of Mersenne primes. I realize that it's not a "very mathematical" statement, so I hope you can read my point in between the lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

p = 3, 5, 17, 107 and 521 are the only numbers known where $2^p - 1$ is a Mersenne prime and p+2 is a prime. Since Mersenne primes are so rare, Mersenne primes where p is a twin prime are even rarer.

I don't know of any particular reason why p+2 shouldn't be a prime and $2^{p+2} - 1$ shouldn't be a Mersenne prime if $2^p - 1$ is a Mersenne prime, so I wouldn't bet my life that there are no other twin Mersenne primes.

On the other hand, the primes p where $2^p - 1$ is a Mersenne prime seem to have an exponential distribution (very roughly the same number with x ≤ p < 10x for every x), so I wouldn't think the chance is more than one in 100,000 that another p exists. The last two known Mersenne primes have p ≈ 58,000,000 and q ≈ 74,000,000, so the chances that p+2 belongs to a Mersenne prime were quite slim.

You could ask whether there are consecutive primes p, q such that $2^p - 1$ and $2^q - 1$ are both Mersenne primes; there are two more examples with p = 2 and p = 13, but still not very likely.

You could ask whether there are more p with $2^p - 1$ a Mersenne prime and p+2 a prime; heuristically there should be infinitely many but they should be so rare that none might ever be found.